# Angular Proxy in root level

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an Angular application and a landing page written in jQuery.

I want to serve the landing page every time the request is on the root of `http://mywebsite.com`. Anything else, let's say `http://mywebsite.com/otherpage`, I want to serve the Angular application.

With `nginx` (production), this is fairly easy.

When developing Angular, we can easily proxy other requests, like `/api`, with `--proxy-config proxy.config.json` CLI option.

The problem I'm getting is with the root level.

What am I doing wrong? Can't I proxy the root level?

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) tells us to go to [Webpack dev-server docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), but still I couldn't figure out how to do it.

My `proxy.config.json` is like the following:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/": {
    "index": "",
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a working proxy config which just intercepts the root and not a angular application served with baseHref. You need to use a `.js` config (https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries) with an exclusion defined for `http-proxy-middleware` (https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching). The config below proxies every request expect when it starts with `/otherpage`. The angular application should use '/otherpage' as baseHref

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/**",
      "!/otherpage**"
    ],
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Angular - but then I can't see any way to configure `http-proxy-middleware` for an out-of-the-box Angular application?

Comment: angular uses the [proxy support](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) in the `weback` development server. Which is `http-proxy-middleware`. See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a conflict with the root level after all.

Changing to other level, I could make it work.

The documentation is not explanatory on this.

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy
- https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 1):

It works if you set `devServer.index` to a falsy value.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

> Note that requests to root won't be proxied by default. To enable root proxying, the `devServer.index` option should be specified as a falsy value:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    devServer: {
        index: '', // specify to enable root proxying
        host: '...',
        contentBase: '...',
        proxy: {
        context: () => true,
        target: 'http://localhost:1234'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you do this in an out-of-the-box Angular application? The `devServer` configuration doesn't appear to be exposed by default?

Comment: Never mind - I've figured it out. I can add `devServer` to my `customWebpackConfig` (using the Angular `custom-webpack` builder)

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The solution below worked for me at time of writing, but no longer seems to work with later versions of Webpack/Angular.

@Zygimantas has suggested a solution in the comments below, but unfortunately that doesn't work for me either.

---

I got this to work as follows:

In `angular.json`:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./my-custom-webpack.config.js"
      },

  ...

  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "proxyConfig": "webpack-proxy.conf.js",

  ...
```

In `my-custom-webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    index: '' // Allows us to proxy the root URL
  }
}
```

In `webpack-proxy.conf.js`

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
  context: [
    '/'
  ],
  target: 'http://proxy-to-url',
  bypass: function(request) {
    // proxy the root URL, plus "/api/*" - otherwise serve using Angular
    return /^\/(api\/.*)?$/.test(request.url) ? null : '/index.html';
  },
  secure: false
}];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

(Needs `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` installed: `npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack`)

Comment: `my-custom-webpack.config.js` should be:

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      index: "",
    },
  },
};

Comment: @Zygimantas should it? Why? The above works fine for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if I don't change the `webpack.config.js` according to suggestion of @Zygimantas. I assume, they changed the configuration in webpack. Also see documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Comment: Hmm - there has been a change in webpack and/or Angular, which means my solution above doesn't work any more. I've tried using @Zygimantas' solution, but that doesn't work for me either... :-(